# append space in URL in form of variable

Tags: url

I have an url say.

```
WWW.XYZ.COM
```

I have a varibale in bakend contains space in it. Then i want to add it with that url.

```
eg.www.xyz.com/variable   or www.xyz.com/stack over
```

But url is not going to accept it. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical URL embed %20 in place of space.
That means your url `www.xyz.com/stack over`will be treated as `www.xyz.com/stack%20over`. So, there can be a solution , write a function that will retrive data from backend as a %20 in every space. Then that will make an url. And try to make the pages appended as %20.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `url encode` like function to eliminate some characters (converting to other composite characters).  Example of [url encode in php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Answer (score 0):

**Theory:**
From [HTML URL Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

> - URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set.
> - Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has to be converted into a valid ASCII format.
> - URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.
> - URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or with %20.

In other words, every character ('a', 'b', '', '_', ...) can be replace with its correspondant ASCII representation.
For example, the ASCII representation of space is %20.

**Example:** When you want to send the attribute "text" containing "Hello World" through a formular or URL, the web-server will process the input "text=Hello%20World" or, less frequent "text=Hello+World".

**Your example:** So, your URL `www.xyz.com/stack over` will be mostly represented as `www.xyz.com/stack%20over`

**Reserved characther**
`= | ; | / | # | ? | : | space` are reserved characters. [RFC 1630](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1630)

Answer (score 0):

Say for Ex : this is your Stackoverflow URL

"stackoverflow.com/questions/51166674/append-space-in-url-in-form-of-variable"

Just Remove "-" in that.

Click Enter.

You Will See the same page with url

"stackoverflow.com/questions/51166674/append%20space%20in%20url%20in%20form%20of%20variable"

Just add %20 instead of space. I hope May be this is helpfull.

Thank you